# Trying to return a view and list through Action method in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to return a view and list through Action method in mvc but getting error.Here i am passing the list of data in 'Detail.PlantName' through view() along with the view name "MasterPage";

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormData person)
{
 TempData["EmpId"] = person.EmpId.ToString();
 FormData Detail = new FormData();
 Detail.PlantName = PopulatePlant(TempData["EmpId"].ToString());       
 return View("MasterPage",, Detail.PlantName.ToList());
}



private static List<SelectListItem> PopulatePlant(string empID)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> PName = new List<SelectListItem>();
            String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
            OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT DISTINCT PARAM.PAR_CD ,PARAM.PAR_DESC1 FROM PARAM WHERE PARAM.PAR_TYP = 'LOC' AND PAR_REG_IND = 'X' and Param.Par_Cd in (select plant_code from user_level_access where token_no = :token_no) ", connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":token_no", empID);
            using (OracleDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    PName.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = sdr["PAR_DESC1"].ToString(),
                        Value = sdr["PAR_CD"].ToString()
                    });
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            return PName;
        }
```

model

```
namespace Rm_Module.Models
{
    public class FormData
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> PlantName { get; set; }
        public int? PlantId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

in the MasterPage.cshtml

```
@model IList<Rm_Module.Models.FormData>
<body class="index-page"> 
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-index">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>                            
                          <i class="material-icons">home</i> Home                            
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlantId,Model.PlantName, "Please Select");
                        </li>
                   </ul>
       </div>
}
```

But not able to bind data in view.Any idea would be appreciated for how to achieve it.getting error"Listdoesnot conatan a definition for 'PlantName'and no method 'PlantName' accepting a first argument of type List"

Comment: Because your model is a collection, not a single `FormData` object. And the model you are passing to the view is `List<SelectListItem>` so none of your code is making much sense

Comment: What you want is `return View("MasterPage", Detail);` and in the view `@model FormData`

Comment: i want to do return View("MasterPage", Detail); and in the view @model FormData  and bind dropdownlist  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlantId,Model.PlantName, "Please Select");  but how to achive it ..any idea

Comment: Just exactly as I stated in my previous comment. What is it you are not understanding?

Comment: how to pass list of data from controller to view at the same time along with view.

Comment: What list are you referring to (the only list in your code is `PlantName` which you are already passing). Have you even tried it yet??

Comment: Yes PlantName along with plantid but getting error "Listdoesnot conatan a definition for 'PlantName'and no method 'PlantName' accepting a first argument of type List"

Comment: FGS - then you did not do as I said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now what you are returning to the view is a list of SelectListItems. A list of SelectListItems is not the same as a list of FormData objects, which is what the view is expecting.

Either way, your model is a list and therefore will never have a property named "PlantId" or "PlantName", which you want to use in your DropdownList. A single FormData object though, does have those properties.

Therefore, as mentioned in the comments, you just need to

1) return the correct model object to your view:

```
return View("MasterPage", Detail);
```

and

2) set your view's model to simply

```
@model Rm_Module.Models.FormData
```

so it accepts a single FormData object - not a list of them.

Comment: @Mohan Actually the answer is pretty much the same as what Stephen suggested in the comments, but thanks. I think you just need to think through the logic of your code a little more when you're making it, it's kind of like a jigsaw where you're nearly there but not quite putting all the parts together correctly.

Comment: @stephen Thx..to you also ...and Adyson seriously your little guidance boost up my moral high..